# ReactJs How to re-call API after initial render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Home component with a `searchbar`.

```
const Intro = (props) => {

    return (
        <Searchbar 
        onSubmit={props.onSubmit}
        onChange={props.onChange} 
        value={props.value}
        header='Nutrion'>
        </Searchbar>
    )
}
```

Searchbar is a controlled component. It get's passed event handlers

```
handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            food: this.state.value,
            submitted: true
        })
    }
```

If the value inside Searchbar get's submitted, it sets state`food: this.state.value` and `submitted: true`.

```
submitted && <Redirect to={{
           pathname: `/search/results`,
           search: `?food=${food}`,
                        }} />
```

`Submitted true` triggers a redirect to Results component, passing along a query string with the submitted food in the searchbar.

```
   componentDidMount() {
        console.log('hiii')
        const food = this.state.food || queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).food
        fetchRecipes(food).then(recipes => {
            if (recipes === null) {
                return this.setState (
                    {
                        error: 'Server failed to respond. Please try again.',
                        loading: false
                    })
            }

            this.setState( {
                error: null,
                recipes: recipes,
                loading: false,
                isFetched: true
            })
        })

    }
```

Here is the problem. This is the `ComponentDidMount()` inside the redirected to `class Results`. It takes the query string we passed earlier and parses it. The result of this is used for an API request and the returning data is passed to `this.state.recipes`. Everything works. Data gets passed to the `recipeList`

```
{!this.state.loading && <Recipelist recipes={this.state.recipes} />}
```

But this only works on INITIAL render. If i change this.state.food by submitting the value inside (another) Searchbar inside Results, it doesn't re-request API data and update RecipeList with new Recipes. How can you make a new API request each item a new value is submitted to `this.state.food` and re-render RecipeList?

I have posted links to relevant files below:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Searchbar from './../ui/Searchbar'

import { 
    Jumbotron,
    // PageHeader
 } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Intro = (props) => {
    
    return (
        <Searchbar 
        onSubmit={props.onSubmit}
        onChange={props.onChange} 
        value={props.value}
        header='Nutrion'>
        </Searchbar>
    )
}

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            submitted: false,
            food: '',
            value: ''
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
     handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            food: this.state.value,
            submitted: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        // REMINDER: toegang tot path is via this.props.match => match.url object
        const submitted = this.state.submitted
        const food = this.state.food

        return (
            
                <Jumbotron>
                    {
                        !submitted && 
                        <Intro onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.value}/> 
                    }
                    {
                        submitted && 
                        <Redirect to={{
                            pathname: `/search/results`,
                            search: `?food=${food}`,
                        }} />
                    }
                </Jumbotron>
            
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Jumbotron} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Searchbar from './../../ui/Searchbar'
import { fetchRecipes } from './../../utils/api'
import queryString from 'query-string'
import Recipelist from './Recipelist'

class Results extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            food: '',
            recipes: null,
            isFetched: false,
            error: null,
            loading: true
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('hiii')
        const food = this.state.food || queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).food
        fetchRecipes(food).then(recipes => {
            if (recipes === null) {
                return this.setState (
                    {
                        error: 'Server failed to respond. Please try again.',
                        loading: false
                    })
            }

            this.setState( {
                error: null,
                recipes: recipes,
                loading: false,
                isFetched: true
            })
        })
        
    }

   
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState( {
            food: this.state.value
        })
    }

    render(){

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <p> Loading ... </p>
        }
         if (this.state.error) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.error}</p>
          {/*<Link to='/'>try again</Link>*/}
        </div>
      )
    }
        return (
            <div>
            <Jumbotron>
                <Searchbar
                value={this.state.value}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </Jumbotron>
             {!this.state.loading && <Recipelist recipes={this.state.recipes} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Results
```

```js
{
  "name": "nutrion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize-css": "^2.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "query-string": "^4.3.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.68.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you have a redirect inside an ui component ? What version of react router are you using?  submit package.json

Comment: Added package.json. I have a redirect because i want the homepage as a clean introduction UI, redirecting to search/results after i submitted a food query. Inside search/results, i want to still be able to do api calls. A bit like Google.com. https://github.com/hyrosian/nutrion is github link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to place a call to fetchRecipes(food) within the handleSubmit

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let recipes = await = fetchRecipes(food);
    let food = e.target.value;
    this.setState( {
        food, recipes
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh ofcourse! Was lost complexity, all new for me.Thanks!